# Rails asset_url not providing correct url in rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, asset-pipeline, rails-engines

I am trying to import content into my database from an engine through a rake task. The files the rake task is pulling in contain erb and image tags.

Everything works fine, but the asset_url tags are not producing the correct url. For instance:

```
<%= image_tag asset_url('subfolder/Marathon.jpg') %>
```

produces the url '/subfolder/Marathon.jpg' instead of '/assets/subfolder/Marathon.jpg'

Is there something I need to include in the rake task for this to work properly?

Here is part of my rake task that loads the partial where the content and images are:

```
task :it => :environment do
  ac = ActionController::Base.new()
  content = ac.render_to_string partial: "subfolder/landing"
  puts content
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried simply

```
<%= image_tag 'subfolder/Marathon.jpg' %>
```

And in your Rake task

```
action_view = ActionView::Base.new(Rails.configuration.paths["app/views"])
action_view.class_eval do
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
  include ApplicationHelper
end
content = action_view.render(:template => 'subfolder/landing', :layout => nil, :format => 'html')
```

Comment: Yes, it was yielding the same results, without adding 'assets' to the path.